# How to set volume control using a mouse shortcut?

Tags: 12.04, volume-control

I used to be able to use btnx in ubuntu 11.10 to do this, but now i can't find the software from the software centre. can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install btnx, you can use these .deb files:

- 32 bit: [main program](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/btnx/0.4.11-3ubuntu2) / [gui](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/btnx-config/0.4.9-4ubuntu1)
- 64 bit: [main program](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/btnx/0.4.11-3ubuntu2) / [gui](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/btnx-config/0.4.9-4ubuntu1)

EDIT: Convenience.

Comment: Thanks, but after downloading the deb file and running it, it says dependency is not satisfiable: btnx-config (>=0.4.9)

Comment: maybe i should use source or sth like that to install, but i dont really know how to do this. perhaps it is time for me to learn doing so.

Comment: i am sorry, i just saw the gui link, will try doing it now

Comment: Awesome! Be sure to mark my answer as the solution, so that people know this issue is solved. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Did not work for me. Better follow these instructions:
[How to set volume control using a mouse shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129996/how-to-set-volume-control-using-mouse-shortcut-in-ubuntu-12-04)

if needed: sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete
then: Ctrl-Windows-right_click on top panel -> Add to Panel... -> Indicator Applet Complete

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the volume with the wheel of the mouse when you are in the corners of the screen, I can suggest you this : 
[Volumouse for Linux](https://github.com/pzim-devdata/Tools-for-Linux/tree/master/Volumouse)